# Reuse the same recipe for multiple datasets

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I want to use the same recipe that I use for one dataset for rest of my datasets.The structure/headers of all the datasets is same. Is there a way to import or reuse the same recipe without doing all the steps again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just getting started with DataPrep, but in my understanding you could feed all your sources into the recipe at the start, then fork them back out at the end and use a schedule to run each one.

Say you have five input files with identical structure but representing different sales markets. Import all five, and if there's no `market` column then use a recipe to `derive` a new column with a static value.

`UNION` all of these into the recipe (so the core recipe receives one file).

At the end of the recipe, add a new recipe for each output which runs `KEEP`, keeping only the data for that market. This will generate five outputs.

Schedule each of these recipes, and when the schedule runs you will get five different outputs - one for each input.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam

Answer (score 1):

In the flow view page, you can "swap" the datasource for a recipe. If you want to use different follow-on steps for different data sources, you can "make a copy" of the recipe and then swap the data source of the copied recipe.

For more details, see https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Flow-View-Page_57344806

Comment: Thanks a lot  Lars